# Arrayadapter only returning the last element

Tags: android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm new to android development and right now I'm trying to parse an J SON array into object and then save each object into a array list then display the array list with a array adapter. But, right now I can only get the array adapter to display the last element.

Here is the main class

```
public class Venue extends Activity {

      Venue_Listing venue = new Venue_Listing();
      ArrayList<Venue_Listing> venueList;
      ListView listview;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

          new GetVenus().execute(URL);
          venueList = new ArrayList<Venue_Listing>();
     }

     private class GetVenus extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

          ProgressDialog dialog;
          String data;

               protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    dialog = new ProgressDialog(Venue.this);
                    dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
                    dialog.show();
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
               }

               protected Boolean doInBackground(String... url) {
                    try {
                         HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url[0]);
                         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                         int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                         if (status == 200) {
                             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                             data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                         }
                         return true;
                    } 
                    catch (ParseException e1) {
                          e1.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                     dialog.cancel();
                     Venue_Listing_Adapter adapter = new                

                     Venue_Listing_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.venue_list_layout, venueList);
                     try {
                         JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);
                         for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                              JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                   if (venue != null) {
                                         venue.SET_ID(object.getString("venue_ID"));
                                         venue.SET_NAME(object.getString("name"));

                                         listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                                   }        
                          }

                     }  
                     catch (JSONException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                     }  
                }
          }
   }
```

This class holds all the J SON parse data

```
public class Venue_Listing {

     private String ID;
     private String NAME;

public Venue_Listing() {
}

public Venue_Listing(String ID, String NAME) {
     super();
     this.ID = ID;
     this.NAME = NAME; 
}

// setter & getter....
```

And here is what I have for my array adapter

```
public class Venue_Listing_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Venue_Listing> {

private ArrayList<Venue_Listing> objects;

public Venue_Listing_Adapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Venue_Listing> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.venue_list_layout, null);
    }

    Venue_Listing i = objects.get(position); 

    if (i != null) {
        TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

        if (id != null ){
            id.setText(i.GET_ID());
        }


        if (name != null) {
            name.setText(i.GET_NAME());
        }
    }

    return v;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Please print and check the values of 'venueList'.
You have not added values in 'venueList' object.

You need to create 'venue' object every time and add object 'venue' in 'venueList'. Hence you are not getting all items in list view.

The Code may go this way: -

```
Venue_Listing venue;
                 try {
                     JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(data);
                     for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                          JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                          venue = new Venue_Listing();
                               if (object != null) {
                                     venue.SET_ID(object.getString("venue_ID"));
                                     venue.SET_NAME(object.getString("name"));
                                     venueList.add(venue);
                               }        
                      }
                      Venue_Listing_Adapter adapter = new Venue_Listing_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.venue_list_layout, venueList);
                      listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                 }  
                 catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```